# Is there a way to launch Selenium automated tests on a Smart TV web browser?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have a set of automated tests (java + selenium) that I would like to launch on a Samsung smart TV web browser.
Did anyone have practical experience launching such kinds of tests?

Comment: What have you tried apart from asking here?

Comment: @Prophet, currently I'm researching. Would like to try Appium + Tizen Driver.